# Is there a way to reflect changes on S3 quickly?

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

I've been working on Django project. Recently sometimes I have a trouble updating static files on S3. The changes on S3 cannot be reflected quickly. Also the speed of reflecting the changes depends on the browser. It takes more time to reflect the changes on Chrome than Edge for me. 
Is there a preferable way to prevent this?

I just did `python manage.py collectstatic` so static files can be updated. when I use Chrome, the files are still not updated even though two hours passed.

Comment: Dear maa, it would be nice if you elaborate a bit on your question and post some code as well as describe problems you experience. It would increase probability of getting an answer.

Comment: That sound like it could be a caching problem. Have you tried clearing the browser cache? In chrome you can try `Shift + F5` or `Ctrl + F5`.

Comment: It worked finally! Thank you so much.. I didn't know that.

Comment: Don't rely on this method in a production environment, since your users won't know about caching. Always make sure when updating static files that you also change their name, otherwise your users might not get the new version. You can use the [ManifestStaticFileStorage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#manifeststaticfilesstorage) or [CachedStaticFileStorage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#cachedstaticfilesstorage) for this purpose.

Comment: Alternatively, make sure S3 sets the caching properties to short period of time (e.g. 10 min) so browsers fetch the newest version at least within this time. This goes at the expense of loading time, since users staying longer on your website will reload existing assets.

Comment: Finally S3 is not really fast for serving content directly to your users, try using a CDN to speed up download times.